# Exchange reports erroring with "ErrorOverBudget" code

Tags: office365, exchange-server

In the past hours I started recieving an unknown error from the Exchange online reports API

```
https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc
```

the error:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"ErrorOverBudget","message":{"lang":"","value":"The current user is running out of budget of the service."}}}
```

These errors started happening without any change in our accounts/configuration/licensing/etc.

What is this error?
How can I fix it?

Comment: `The current user is running out of budget of the service.`

Comment: @KonstantinL but what budget? this is a subscription to O365, the Exchange Admin APIs. also, the error has gone away and now returned for another customer for no apparent reason.